# Reinstalling Android SDK (Xamarin / Visual Studio 2015)

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin

The android-sdk install folder was corrupted during a failed update from the SDK Manager and needs to be reinstalled.

It is being used with the Xamarin Visual Studio 2015 plug in, and I'm not sure if it can be reinstalled "outside" of VS, or if there is an integrated tool that should be used.

As far as I can tell, the only hooks VS has into the SDK are the path references under Tools->Options->Xamarin->Android Settings.

Comment: The **corruption** happened from not properly backing out of the SDK update (by abrubtly closing the SDK Manager window on error). To **prevent** this, click the little **RED STOP SIGN** in the bottom right corner, it will roll back an changes.

Answer (score 2):

You can define any `Android SDK` you'd like. So if you want to reinstall the `Android SDK`, it's as simple as deleting your current `Android SDK` and downloading it again and specifying the path in the `Tools > Options > Xamarin > Android` section.

**Note:** Just be cautious for other programs that might be using it such as other IDEs (Android Studio) and third party programs!

Comment: Ok thanks... No way a bacon scarf and egg shades! I got a stinking hat.

Comment: There was a "Programs and Features" entry for the SDK called "Android SDK Tools" that completely removed it...

Answer (score 1):

The Android SDK can be added/removed just like any other install-able component from the Modify dialog within the VS installer (JDK as well).

Manual modification is therefore somewhat of a hack now (that could lead to unforeseen consequences, which is what I'm trying to avoid).

Comment: There's really not much of a difference between `Uninstalling` via `Control Panel` and deleting the respective files. The Android SDK doesn't really have a real installer per-say.

Comment: Yeah, I don't ever remember their being one, maybe the VS installer put's it there, not sure. It didn't remove the platform folders, which I suppose is nice since they're big downloads...

Comment: My answer isn't to prove you wrong, it's to provide another way. Xamarin's  online docs even have an entire "Manual Installation" section for the SDK, so it is valid. Even though MS should keep things clean and separated, it cannot be assumed this will always be the case.

Answer (score 0):

You can only reinstall SDK, moving files for Android path.

Verify that the AVD can be run, before open Visual Studio.

Can you update version, is necessary to modify path references under Tools-> Options-> Xamarin-> Android Settings

Download: https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html#downloads

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are saying, could you please rephrase (you can just edit your post in place, you don't need to add a new comment)? Thanks.